# I have two disks on azure linux VM, sda and sdb

Tags: linux, azure, disk

I don't use /dev/sdb and I can't delete it. In *Azure->Disks* i have only my Os_Disk 30GB, in VM tab in Disks there is also only Os_Disk.
`fdisk -l` shows 2 disks:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 30 GiB, 32212254720 bytes, 62914560 sectors
Disk model: Virtual Disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: ...

Device      Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1  262144 62914526 62652383 29.9G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda14   2048     8191     6144    3M BIOS boot
/dev/sda15   8192   262143   253952  124M EFI System

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/sdb: 20 GiB, 21474836480 bytes, 41943040 sectors
Disk model: Virtual Disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: ...

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 41940991 41938944  20G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

My VM standard is A2_v2

I am completely new to azure, thanks for help

Comment: What exact type of VM pricing you are using B, D, A, etc?
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/linux/

Comment: @AndriyBilous i have A2_v2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure A_v2-Series VMs have additional temporary disk attached(in your case it is `/dev/sdb`)

The temporary disk provides short-term storage for applications and processes, and is intended to only store data such as page or swap files.

Data on the temporary disk may be lost during a maintenance event, shutdown or when you redeploy a VM. During a successful standard reboot of the VM, data on the temporary disk will persist.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/new-av2-series-vm-sizes/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/managed-disks-overview#temporary-disk